# Saving a XML file in the server folder

Tags: c#, xml, file, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a function in MVC application where the objects are serialized. I am trying to save the contents of the file in a user selected folder and file name. So basically the path and the file name are chosen by the user.

I have tried the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("XmlExport", "LsystemFamilies", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.FamilyID)
    <input type="file" name="fs" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create and export"/>
}
```

With the above method the user can only select a file which already exists in the system.

**Controller**

```
    public void XmlExport(ExportFileName file,HttpPostedFileBasefs)
    {
        var model = new XMLSystemFamily();
        var lsystemfamily = db.LsystemFamily.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LsystemFamilyID==file.FamilyID);
        //Code eliminated
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLSystemFamily));
        //var path = String.Format("{0}xmlfiles", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        //FileStream fs = new FileStream("\\FE0VMC0643\\TeDaLS\\xmlfiles\\"+file.FileName+".xml", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Close();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs.FileName);
        serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, model);
    }
```

The model that is returned from the form is empty. The file name is also empty.
But when I had the user to enter only a file name and as in the commented part of the controller where I created a file with the user entered file name it works perfectly. But when I deploy it in the server I am unable to set a path for creating the xml file.

I have also seen posts where the controller could generate a downloadable link for the xml file. But again I am unable to set a path for writing the xml file. I have already read that it is possible to create a downloadable link without even writing it to a file, but I can't understand how it is possible.

**tl;dr**

- Create a file in a location specified by the user, write to the new file created

or

- Create a downloadable link for the generated xml without saving the file anywhere

Comment: Change the name of your input to `<input type="file" name="fs" />`

Comment: That was a typo; I get a null value for fs in my controller.

Comment: By "server folder", do you mean the application folder, i.e. where the web-site is? because that would be a **really, really** bad idea...

Comment: So is `HttpPosiFileBase` (its `HttpPostedFileBase`). Show the real code.

Comment: @MarcGravell :  Yes.. And thats the reason why I thought if generating a download link for the xml file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  Question edited. This is exactly what I am having right now. It throws NullRefernceException

Comment: There is nothing in your view code to suggest it would not post back. Is that all their is to it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This is exactly what i have in my view.